# Два процесса npm одновременно

Tags: node.js, npm

1)Есть еще варианты запуска нескольких сценариев npm параллейно на Windows,кроме **start** без установки дополнительных пакетов?

```
"dev": "start npm run start && start npm run server"
```

Вариант через одиночный амперсанд не работает...
2)Можно ли одной командой,после команды **start** сразу закрыть два окна,чтобы в каждом не нажимать ctrl+c

Answer (score 1):

Если вы всё же не захотите мучиться и писать shell-велосипеды, то можно просто использовать https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently.

Comment: Получается без велосипедов на windows никак?

Comment: Не подскажите а как одной командой убить эти два окна?

Comment: @Александр Я, конечно, не уверен, но думаю, что при убйстве родителя, дочерние процессы сами умирают. ну или можно через kill <pid>, в powershell может быть аналог.

Comment: Ну kill <pid> это считай наобум,у меня больше 2 процессов node запущено,только если taskkill /F /IM node.exe,тогда дочерние и правда умрут,но все равно придется руками окна закрывать...¯\_(ツ)_/¯